# how to change bootstrap div height and width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[this the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuraJ.png)this is my code.i want to change both div height and width.I try to change but is not working.

```css
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
          container left
 <img src="5.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre"> 
</div><div class="col-sm-4">
Container Right
<img src="5.jpg">
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is actually working. Maybe do you have some other css proprieties overriding it?

Comment: nope..thats why i asking its not working

Comment: The code you gave here shows the result you want. Try to run it and change the window size and you'll see.

Comment: Are you aware that your code will only work with a window size smaller than 500px? If you want to apply it in any case, you will have to take the proprieties of the column outside ```@media```

Comment: I second that. The width and height will only change when the window is smaller than 500px width (`max-width`). This is known as media queries and is used for responsive design. If you want to set the width and height to `50px` no matter the window size, you have to take the whole `.col-sm-4` CSS rule outside of the `@media` code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has quite a few issues.

**Implementation of bootstrap grid system**
First of all in the bootstrap grid system the sizes of the columns in your row have to add up to 12.
This means that the numbers at the end of all your column class names should always add up to 12.
*col-sm-**num***

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Column Left
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Column Right
    </div>
    <!-- Above both column class names end with 6, which adds up to 12 -->
</div>

<!-- Below is another example of the same concept -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Column Left
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Column Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Column Right
    </div>
    <!--Above each of the 3 column class names end with 4 which adds up to 12-->
</div>
<!--Note that the sizes of the columns don't have to be the same.-->
<!--This means that the number at the end can vary from column to column-->
```

Now to answer your question on how to change the width and height of your divs.

**Ways to change div width and height in bootstrap**

**1. Using the built-in bootstrap class.**
Bootstrap has inbuilt classes which allows you to change your divs sizes.
The only issue with it is that it only allows one to change the width/height to 25%, 50%, 75% or 100% of the screen width.
So if you would like to be more specific with the width/height of your div this wouldn't be the best option.

Here's how to apply the built-in classes:

```
<div class="w-25"></div><!--Set the width to 25% of screen width -->
<div class="w-50"></div><!--Set the width to 50% of screen width -->
<div class="w-75"></div><!--Set the width to 75% of screen width -->
<div class="w-100"></div><!--Set the width to 100% of screen width -->

<!--To set the height replace "w" with "h" -->
```

**2. Using the style property in your div tag**
Now, assuming you want to be specific with the width/height of the div this is the way to go
All you will have to do is add the style property in your div and set the width/height using percentages, pixels or em.

For example:

```
<div style="width:100px;"></div><!--Set width to 100 pixels-->
<div style="width:40%;"></div><!--Set width to 40% of the screen width-->
<div style="width: 20em;"></div><!--Set width to 20em of the screen width-->

<!-- To set the height replace "width" with "height" -->
```

Comment: Your answer appears incomplete?

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="w-25 p-3" style="background-color: #eee;">Width 25%</div>
<div class="w-50 p-3" style="background-color: #eee;">Width 50%</div>
<div class="w-75 p-3" style="background-color: #eee;">Width 75%</div>
<div class="w-100 p-3" style="background-color: #eee;">Width 100%</div>


<div style="height: 100px; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);">
  <div class="h-25 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 25%</div>
  <div class="h-50 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 50%</div>
  <div class="h-75 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 75%</div>
  <div class="h-100 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 100%</div>
</div>
```

More info: [Bootstrap sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)